# Роутинг в gem Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, erb

Использую gem devise для авторизации. Хочу задать ассоциацию пользователю User has_many hotels. И задаю route:

```
devise_for :users do
  resources :hotels
end
```

Вызываю хэлпер link_to

```
<%= link_to 'Hotel', current_user.hotels[0] %>
```

и начинается котовасия

> undefined method `hotel_path' for #<#:0x72bdc630>

Что я делаю не так и как мне настроить routes для gem'a devise?

Comment: Вы `rake routes` запустите, и если не станет понятно, добавьте её вывод в вопрос, объясним.

Comment: @D-side прав, покажите routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

Вы немножко перепутали... Подобные ассоциации задаются в моделях, а не в роутах. Вам необходимо обратиться к связи "[ActiveRecord](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations%20%22%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%20Active%20Record)". Думаю, в вашем случае необходимо в модели **hotel.rb** задать `belongs_to :user`, а в модели **user.rb** задать `has_many :hotels`

Comment: Нет, модели связанны через has_many и belongs_to. Интересует именно как создать вложенный маршрут.

Comment: @QNester тут действительно дело в роутах